# redirect on route component based on api response - react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

whenever i load the root url, i load the home component, i need to check whether the cookie is set or not based on a api.

```
<Route path="/" render ={() => {
  // checking the cookie exists
if(cookieExists){
  return (<HomePage />)
}else{
  axios.get("api/userLoggedIn")
     .then(res => {
          // the url is an external url [https://www.examplelogin.com]
          return(<div>Redirecting</div>
          {window.location.assign(res.data)}
          )
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("error in api", err))
}
}}
/>
```

the error i am getting is it - nothing was returned from render in Route component

Comment: You are not returning anything from your else branch. You also can't return the axios request, since that is asynchronous, so the return inside the function given to `then` will not be returned from the function given to `render`.

Comment: so what i can do on this ? any solution. yeah i know its an async so the react will check a return , but since its async it will loade late

Comment: Better to write a HOC rather than render props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return the `<div>Redirecting</div>` synchronously.

```
<Route path="/" render ={() => {
  // checking the cookie exists
if(cookieExists){
  return (<HomePage />)
}else{
  axios.get("api/userLoggedIn")
     .then(res => {
          // the url is an external url [https://www.examplelogin.com]
          window.location.assign(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("error in api", err))
  return <div>Redirecting</div>;
}
}}
/>
```

The `axios` call happens asynchronously and its response gets handled after the redirecting element is returned to the router.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my header and footer shows, i just want to show only the redirecting . I have raised another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153984/redirecting-on-route-component-without-having-the-header-and-footer-component