# redirecting on route component , without having the header and footer component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have a sample application , whenever i am loading the root url i am checking the cookie presist or not , if cookie is there then i load the home page component else , i need redirect to an external url.

I am able to redirect but  whenever i am redirecting the header and footer component shows up. Since i am calling the route component in between header and footer. So how can i show only the text **Redirecting**
without Header and Footer component

```
   <BrowserRouter> 
    <Header />
    <div className="content">
       <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
       <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
       <Route path="/" render ={() => {
         // checking the cookie exists
         if(cookieExists){
           return (<HomePage />)
        }else{
        axios.get("api/userLoggedIn")
            .then(res => {
          // the url is an external url [https://www.examplelogin.com]
          window.location.assign(res.data);
        })
         .catch(err => console.log("error in api", err))
        return <div>Redirecting</div>;
        }
       }}
     />
    </div>
    <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can just use the following styles on your 'div' tag, something like this:

```
const contact = {zIndex: 9999, backgroundColor: "#fff", top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, position: "absolute"};
const wrapper = {position: "relative"}; 

<BrowserRouter>
  <div style={wrapper}>
    <Header />
    <div className="content">
       <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
       <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
       <Route path="/" render ={() => {
         // checking the cookie exists
         if (cookieExists){
           return (<HomePage />)
         } else {
           axios.get("api/userLoggedIn")
           .then(res => {
             // the url is an external url [https://www.examplelogin.com]
             window.location.assign(res.data);
           })
           .catch(err => console.log("error in api", err))
           return <div style={contact}>Redirecting</div>;
         }
       }}/>           
    </div>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The "Redirecting" div has been given a high stack order with zIndex, and other necessary styles to cover the whole screen with a white background; hence it should show in front of all other elements around. Also, an outer "wrapper" div with "position: relative" is required to make it work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `<Header>` and `<Footer>` into each of your pages `AboutUs`, `Contact` and `HomePage`.

There's no other way to conditionally render `<Header>` and `<Footer>` at parent level unless you want to maintain a state at parent level that controls whether to show Header and Footer which is not an ideal solution.

Just wrap them into each of your components - `AboutUs`, `Contact` and `HomePage`.

Comment: So for this, we don't have a solution.