# Prevent component from showing once authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a login flow. Everything is set up correctly and it redirects users to `"/"` once authenticated

My current issue is that when they are authenticated and I type `/login` it will briefly show the login component then redirect back to `"/"`

How can I display a loading component instead or not display Login.js at all once authenticated?

App.js

```
<Switch>
  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

This is how I redirect the user once they have already signed in. This is located in `Login.js`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) history.push("/");
  });
```

Comment: You’ll likely want some state like “isAuthenticating” which is false initially, then becomes true during auth, and false once done (failed or not). This can then be passed to a loader component which conditionally renders.

Comment: I do have isAuthenticating prop also in redux but not sure how I put it together when user is trying to hit /login once authenticated

Comment: Normally, `isAuthenticating` would be set when a user presses the login button, not on a visit to a route.

Comment: This is due to unresolved promises, I solved the problem using `react-loadable` which now is deprecated, so check out [`loadable components`](https://loadable-components.com/docs/getting-started/)! Ah, add the `loadable` function in your router component, then use loadable-processed components inside your routes.

Comment: Did you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153984/redirecting-on-route-component-without-having-the-header-and-footer-component

Comment: Well, the easiest solution would be to place have a conditional render, with `redirect("/")` if logged and displaying the other content if not.

Comment: @TomekBuszewski that is the current flow. The issue is that once logged if I type /login it will render login component which I'm trying to prevent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using my `isAuthenticating ? <Loading /> : <Login />` within my Login component